# packet lost in tcp stack

Tags: linux, tcp, kernel

I have a tcp connection on linux that will occasionally drop packets in the kernel. Following output from tcpdump(on the server side) shows that NIC has received those packets, but somehow drops them in the kernel, hence there are no ack nor my app could receive anything.

[image: tcpdump output]
ethtool and netstat also suggests that is no packets lost or error occurs below level 2(I confirm that following number won't increase by comparing them before and after the connection closed).

[image: ethtool drop]

[image: ethtool error]

[image: netstat]

In a situation like this, how can I investigate what is going wrong? can anyone point me to the right direction? any tool or parameters from /proc or source code in the kernel.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try https://superuser.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @meyer9 yeah, I read that post before, but it is not the same obviously.

Comment: No, I just mean, this question is probably best for the StackExchange site. It doesn't link to a specific question. This isn't about programming, so it probably shouldn't be posted here.

Comment: First I would double check that you are *really* losing packets. You would not believe how many people believe packets are being lost, when what really is happening is that they are issuing a `read` function for 4096 bytes, and never checking the return value of read, which is much less, depending on how many packets were in the buffer.

Comment: Or vice versa, issuing a `write` for 4096 bytes and not checking the return value, which might be only 802.

Comment: @ZanLynx yes, packets are lost, 100% sure. you can even confirm it from tcpdump, no ack is replied, client keeps resending the packet.

Comment: This isn't a programming question then... If it was my problem, I'd try to trace the other side also. If it isn't getting some of your packets the problem is in the network hardware, like the switches or routers. 

In fact, I have such a buggy router here at home, which Comcast insists I use to support static IPs, which seems to randomly decide IPv6 flows no longer exist, until it recovers. Or drops the connection.